# swift process standart input pipe

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, process

I want to create an encrypted .dmg on macOS using swift

I haven't found an implementation for hdiutil, so I'm forced to use terminal commands for that.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to work with pipes (which should be used regarding apples documentation)

The command i want to trigger is the following: 
`printf 'password' | hdiutil create -encryption AES-256 -volname backupname -stdinpass -size 1GB backupname.dmg`

The code, I've tried is the following (nothing worked):

```
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
        let task = Process()
        let inputpipe = Pipe()
        task.standardInput = inputpipe
        //1. try: inputpipe.fileHandleForReading.write("password".data(using: .utf8)!)
        //2. try: inputpipe.fileHandleForWriting.write("password".data(using: .utf8)!)
        /*3. try: inputpipe.fileHandleForWriting.writeabilityHandler = {
        pipe in
        let inputString = "password"
        let data = inputString.data(using: .utf8)!
        pipe.write(data)
    }*/
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
print(shell("hdiutil", "create", "-encryption", "AES-256", "-volname", "backupname", "-stdinpass", "-size", "1MB", "~/Documents/backupname.dmg"))
```

How do i correctly provide the password using `Process()`

Comment: `~` is usually expanded by the shell (bash by default, on macOS). There's no shell preprocessing your commands here so you'll need to manually expand the `~` to `/Users/Me`

Comment: @Alexander thanks! didn't know that - now its at least generating the file using `inputpipe.fileHandleForWriting.write("password\n".data(using: .utf8)!)` 
Now I've the problem, that waitUntilExit() is in an endless loop - when i terminate the application, the .dmg has been created

Comment: You never closed the file handle, so EOF is never sent. hdiutil has no way to tell that you've sent all your data, so it just keeps listening until it reads EOF

Comment: @Alexander thanks again!
Closing the fileHandly using `inputpipe.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile()` did the job